# Hosting two websites from same Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-server

i have a website already set up which is working perfectly. Now i want to setup another in the same server but it gives error **Unable to locate the server named "ct-ttm.xceedance.com" --- the server does not have a DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again**

here is my virtual host conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ct-ttm.xceedance.com
        ServerAlias www.ct-ttm.xceedance.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ct-ttm/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/ct-ttm/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Old website is working fine and i have configured the above code similarly. But above one is not working while below one is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ttm.xceedance.com
        ServerAlias www.ttm.xceedance.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ttm.com/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/ttm.com/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: _"the server does not have a DNS entry"_ ...

Comment: See [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thankyou for the comment. Can you please guide me to the file path where i can add this DNS entry?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thankyou for the comment. Can you please guide me to the file path where i can add this DNS entry?

Comment: Your domain uses GoDaddy for DNS service. You need to add the required entrie(s)  via their control panel.